# debuging "undefined" or "<internal structure>" for Json decode and similiar

Tags: json, debugging, elm

I have a large (>8 elements) object that contains a potentially empty list of strings `ids`.

I'd like to read the data in and parse in elm. Initially my attempts returned `<internal structure>` or `undefined`.

I found the problem to be not handling nulls. It took me a long time to diagnose and testing each of the elements is tedious. I don't know where to look for compiler or run time hints. How does one approach this in elm?

Are there established ways to quickly validate an Elm model against a javascript object? Are there good places to put `Debug.*` statements? Ways to test with the repl?

The Object

```
 # curl '0.0.0.0:3003/person_search_view?select=ids'|jq -c
 [{"ids":["11488"]},{"ids":["11489"]},{"ids":[null]}]
```

The code

```
-- testing what part is failing
-- *tedious* made a function to test reading in each type [List String, String, Int] 
justID : (List String) -> Person
justID ids =
  Person 0 "" "" "" "" "" ""   0 "" 0 0 0 ids [""] [""] ""

stringlist : Decode.Decoder (List String)
stringlist = list (oneOf [string, null "N/A"] )

memberDecoderID : Decode.Decoder Person
memberDecoderID =
  Decode.succeed
    justID
    |: ("ids"      := stringlist  ) -- here was failing (List string)

fetchAllUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:3003/person_search_view?order=curage"

fetchAll : Effects Action
fetchAll =
  Http.get (Decode.list memberDecoderID ) fetchAllUrl
 |> Task.toResult
 |> Task.map FetchAllDone 
 |> Effects.task
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend building unit tests for your custom decoders. Not only that, but I would recommend *starting* with unit tests when building any decoders. If you start building unit tests around the smallest decoders possible using JSON values appropriate to what you'd see in the real world, you will probably catch errors much faster, and you'll be guaranteed to future-proof your code because each error you've caught along the way will have to be fixed via a backwards-compatible unit test.

For example, you could use the entertainingly-named [deadfoxygrandpa/elm-test](https://github.com/deadfoxygrandpa/elm-test) library and write tests like the following:

```elm
-- in your CustomDecoders.elm file...
stringlist : Decode.Decoder (List String)
stringlist = list (oneOf [string, null "N/A"] )

-- in your CustomDecoders-Tests.elm file...
tests : Test
tests = 
  suite "A Test Suite"
    [ test "stringlist decodes string lists"
      <| assertEqual (decodeString stringlist "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]") (Ok ["1","2","3"])
    , test "stringlist decodes null"
      <| assertEqual (decodeString stringlist "[null]") (Ok ["N/A"])
    ]
```

You still may have to deal with cryptic JSON parsing error messages, but now you'll have a much easier time finding the problem since you'll know exactly which tests fail.